# How to escape a semicolon in C++ string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

```
std:string str("text1\; text2\;");
```

How come VS2005 says `; unrecognized character escape sequence.`

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: why do you think it needs escaping?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because this is wrong:

```
std:string str("text1\; text2\;");
```

This is correct:

```
std::string str("text1; text2;");
```

TWO colons after std.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to escape semicolons

Answer (score 3):

Just put the semicolon with no backslash:

```
std::string str("text1; text2;");
```

Comment: Don't forget the `std::` prefix missing a colon.

Answer (score 3):

Semicolons have absolutely *no* significance in C strings; they're just normal characters there. If you need to put a backslash in the string because something later requires it, it's the backslash that needs the backslash in front.

```
std::string str("text1\\; text2\\;");
```

That's because `\;` is not a recognized escape sequence in C++; the compiler rightly wants to know what on earth you're talking about when you put that in.